# How do I compare against multiple values in the condition of a while loop

Tags: c, loops

I have an array of `structs` that are populated with some values. I am prompting the user to input a value. I then need to check the array to see if the value the user has entered is contained in the array.
If it is found, then the program will continue execution.
If it is not found, then the program will prompt the user to enter a different value.

Below is the code I have written already. You can see I have tried to scan the array as part of the do-while loop condition, but this is not working.

```
do
{
    printf("Insert the number you want to search:\n");
    numero = getInputFromUser();  
} while (for (i = 0;  i < numAlunos; i++) // This is where I need help
             numero != vAlunos[i].numero)
```

How can I scan an array as part of a loop condition?

Comment: Write a new function that will perform the search and return whether it was found or not. You can then use the function in your while loop condition.

Comment: I have attempted to reword your question and cleanup the code that was there to focus it on the issue you mentioned. If I have not cleaned it up correctly, please feel free to edit it further or unroll what I have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using C99 then you have access to stdbool.h and can use the boolean type, if not, just adjust this as appropriate to whatever you use as a `bool` replacement, such as a typedef, #define, or just return 0 and 1 with int.

I am also making an assumption that your array of structs and the array length variable are global, but if they aren't you can just modify this function to pass them in as arguments.

```
bool checkForValue(int numeroToSearch) // Guessing int, but change as needed
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0;  i < numAlunos; i++)
    {
        if(numeroToSearch == vAlunos[i].numero)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you should be able to use it like this:

```
do
{
    printf("Insert the number you want to search:\n");
    number= validar_insert (2150001, 2169999);//check if the input is between this values

    printf("That number doeste exist.\n");
    printf("Enter another number.\n");
}while (!checkForValue(numero))
```

Comment: I get all that you said except on thing: how can I get the "numeroToSearch" in order to use it in the checkForValue function ? I would have to return it from the function where is use the loop, right ? I

Comment: @NelsonSilva - You pass it to the function. If you look at the do-while loop code I posted you see I am passing in `numero`. I just called it `numeroToSearch` in the function to make it clear what it was. The do-while loop I added is taken directly from your example code, the only thing I did was took the for loop you had listed in the condition of the do-while and moved it to a function that I then called from the condition of the do-while.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a compiler extension, both GCC and Clang provide [statement-expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) that can be embedded inside the condition:

```
do {
    printf("Insert the number you want to search:\n");
    numero = getInputFromUser();
} while (({
    int i = 0;

    while(i < numAlunos && vAlunos[i] != numero)
        ++i;

    i == numAlunos; // "return value" of the statement-expressions
}));
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a46a230d58e1db9)